# Matlab drawing tetrahedrons and triangles

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d, rendering, matlab-figure

I'm implementing Crust algorithm in MATLAB and having problem to draw result figure.

I have an array pointsArray (1000x3) of points in three-dimensional space.

1. I have a matrix M (100x4). Each row is a vector containing 4 indexes of pointsArray, making a tetrahedron. Now I want to draw all these tetrahedrons in some efficient way.

   Currently I'm using "for" loop and patch(FV) method, but for few thousands tetrahedron it's killing my CPU.
2. I have a matrix N (100x3). Each row is a vector containing 3 indexes of pointsArray, making a triangle in three-dimensional space. I also want to draw these triangles.

Any ideas, how to draw these figures in some efficient way?

Edit: problem solved. I used trisurf instead of patch.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding second question (triangulated surfaces), I use the following code:

```
%% Wire plot
% The idea is to plot all triangles as one line. But to make part of the
% line connecting two triangles invisible, add NaN after each 3 points of
% triangle.

NTri = size(N,1);
X = reshape(pointsArray(N.',1), 3, NTri);   X = reshape([X; nan(1,NTri)], 4*NTri, 1);
Y = reshape(pointsArray(N.',2), 3, NTri);   Y = reshape([Y; nan(1,NTri)], 4*NTri, 1);
Z = reshape(pointsArray(N.',3), 3, NTri);   Z = reshape([Z; nan(1,NTri)], 4*NTri, 1);
figure;
plot3(X,Y,Z,'-k.');
axis equal

%% Surface plot
% patch also can plot all triangles at once. I use the following code to
% plot triangulated objects consisting of more than 300000 triangles and it
% is very fast.

px = [pointsArray(N(:,1),1) pointsArray(N(:,2),1) pointsArray(N(:,3),1)].';
py = [pointsArray(N(:,1),2) pointsArray(N(:,2),2) pointsArray(N(:,3),2)].';
pz = [pointsArray(N(:,1),3) pointsArray(N(:,2),3) pointsArray(N(:,3),3)].';
figure
patch(px,py,pz, 'g');
axis equal
```

Hope it will be helpful to someone.

// Oleg

Answer (score 0):

Try to change [figure `render` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#RendererMode) to `opengl`

```
   set(gcf,'Render','OpenGL');
```

However it works only for triangles in 3D. The tetrahedrons can be represented as 2 triangles.